# jquery mouse down event override.

Tags: jquery, events, window

If I have a window and assign an event then attempts to over right it like so.

```
$( win ).mousedown( function ( e ) { alert( 1 ) } )
$( win ).mousedown( function ( e ) { alert( 2 ) } )
```

my second event is the one that fires ( I get alert 2 ) , as I would expect. Though when I move this window to another child window(window.open) the first event is copped not the second.

Example:
make a new window called newBrowserWindow then

```
newBrowserWindow.document.body.appendChild( win );// copy in div
```

once I click on my window in the new browser window I get alert 1 not 2?

Comment: Could you share a jsfiddle?

Comment: trying but its not calling the JS I add, new to jsfiddle I may figure it out.

Comment: I could try to fix it for you if you share relevant code

Comment: I got it to work but my div will not show.  http://jsfiddle.net/blazeeboy/fNPvf/

Comment: the share is out of date? It didnt share the right code

Comment: ok here we go. http://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/2994/

Comment: Here both alerts are shown: http://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/2996/

Comment: I never was able to put in the bad code because the neither of the mousedown's work for me. Only the alert(win) fires. It should create a div with the text "hello world" but that does no appear for me. Guessing its a jsfiddle thing?

Answer (score 0):

just did a simple .unbind( 'mousedown' ); before re assigning the new event.